# Regex: Prefix each word within quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

Using javascript and regex, I would like to prefix each word, that is within quotes, with a plus.

Given the following string:

```
"this is in quotes" not in quote "more quotes"
```

I would like to return this:

```
"+this +is +in +quotes" not in quote "+more +quotes"
```

After that, I would like to remove all the quotation marks, which is not a problem using a simple replace, but if this can all be accomplished in one regex, that would be cool.

I know I can use `\"(.*?)\"` to select everything in quotes, and `(?<![^ ])(?=[^ ])` selects the beginning of each word, but I don't know how to put it all together.

Comment: Does it have to be a single regex to select each word inside quotes? It's way easier to just extract the portion of the string in quotes and process it.

Comment: not really prossible with regexes to parse delimited patterns (eg strings, xml-tags). Better do it in a char-by-char parsing manner. There is a solution using regexes but is not correct strictly speaking since start and end of strings are not easy to process with regex, it is possible errors will happen

Comment: @VLAZ no, it doesn't have to be a single regex. It's just a bonus if that's possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that with one regex!

The idea is to look forward and only match words that are followed by "...chars quote valid-string", where "valid-string" contains either no quotes or balanced pairs of quotes.

```js
quotes_re = `
    \\w+          # a word

    (?=           # followed by ..

        [^"]*     # plain text (possibly empty), and then...
        "         # a quote, and then...
        (
            [^"]+      # some plain text
            |          # or
            " [^"]* "  # a quoted string
        )*             # 0 or more times
        
        $         # end of string    
    )
`;

let regex = (src, flags) => 
     new RegExp(src.replace(/#.*|\s+/g, ''), flags);

s = '"this is in quotes" not in quote "more quotes" end end'

console.log('regex', regex(quotes_re, 'g').source)
console.log('result', s.replace(regex(quotes_re, 'g'), '+$&'))
```

The `regex` utility provides verbose regexes support for JS, you can obtain the raw source by logging `regex(quotes_re, 'g').source`

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much, @georg

Comment: I really like this. Just for the sake of brevity, the full regex in one one is `quotes_re = '\\w+(?=[^"]*"([^"]+|" [^"]* " )*$)'`

Answer (score 3):

You can match the section inside quotes first and use [a replacer function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) that will change each word by appending a `+` in front of it.

```js
let input = '"this is in quotes" not in quote "more quotes"';

let stringInQuotesRegex = /"[^"]+"/g;

let output = input.replace(stringInQuotesRegex, replacer)

console.log(output)

function replacer(match) {
  let eachWordRegex = /\w+/g;
  return match.replace(eachWordRegex, "+$&");
}
```